# Blend image script

Tags: html, google-sheets

Hello I'm trying to blend two images, one for the background and a QR code. This is the code that I'm trying to use on spreadsheet script, but I get in my email two separate images.

```
'<img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-fmBhw5ZfMYE/XDLZiPjJSpI/AAAAAAAABJw/OMLi2ZHOvyIKYPve8Pv2Lqu9ANzMTU83ACLcBGAs/s800/IMG_9731.JPG" id="image-1"><img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" id="image-2"></div><div class="demo"><div class="image-1"></div><div class="image-2"></div><div class="bg-blend"></div></div>'
```

HTML from above string:

```
<img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-fmBhw5ZfMYE/XDLZiPjJSpI/AAAAAAAABJw/OMLi2ZHOvyIKYPve8Pv2Lqu9ANzMTU83ACLcBGAs/s800/IMG_9731.JPG" id="image-1">
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=" id="image-2">
</div>
<div class="demo">
  <div class="image-1"></div>
  <div class="image-2"></div>
  <div class="bg-blend"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to do styling in css file, for more reference follow this url http://www.webdesigndev.com/position-one-image-image-css/

Comment: @DHARMENDRASINGH How I do that on google spreadsheet script section?